# The animator RelativeLayout was obscured by the softKeybord when it pop up

Tags: android, animation, invisible, animator

The animator `RelativeLayout` was obscured by the `softKeyboard` when it pops up. But at the end of animation, some view in `RelativeLayout` is still invisible.

Here are two screenshots:

Before animation

[image]

After animation

[image]

Comment: Hi stackoverflow works best when you ask a specific question.

Comment: Hi,thanks.u mean the problem I described is not clear?I'm sorry that it really hard to describe,so the screenshot may help to understand.